# can't compile simple file with clang

Tags: c++, clang

I have a simple cpp file (just an empty `int main() {}`) and I'm calling clang with

```
clang.exe -cc1 -std=c++11 file.cpp
```

however it doesn't matter where I put file.cpp (I usually put it in the same directory of the clang executable) clang will always complain that

```
clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'file.cpp'
clang.exe: error: no input files
```

what's wrong with that?

---

Edit: I also tried with full path:

```
D:\clang\llvmclang-build\Debug\bin>clang -cc1 "D:/clang/llvmclang-build/Debug/bin/file.cpp"

error: error reading 'D:/clang/llvmclang-build/Debug/bin/file.cpp'
1 error generated.
```

since the file exists and there's nothing else, this error message isn't very informative. Also tried with:

```
"D:\\clang\\llvmclang-build\\Debug\\bin\\file.cpp"
```

and

```
"D:\clang\llvmclang-build\Debug\bin\file.cpp"
```

the error is exactly the same

Comment: Have you tried to specify the full path for file.cpp?

Comment: It's strange to put it where the compiler is. Normally you'd run the compiler in the same directory where the source file is but the compiler would be somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, that didn't work out, I'm editing the post

Comment: @user3834459 that's not a windows path you need to use backslashes to separate the folders like `D:\clang\llvmclang-build\Debug\bin\file.cpp`

Comment: @PeterT same error with \\ and \ : (

Comment: @user3834459 and the file opens fine when you do `notepad D:\clang\llvmclang-build\Debug\bin\file.cpp` ?

Comment: @PeterT Yes, posted an answer for future readers >:(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Argh, stupid *Windows-hiding-known-file-extensions* thing!!

[image]

Sorry for the firedrill :(

That's why I hate working on windows..

Comment: I always change that setting in File Manager as soon as I hit any Windows box.